# Creating an AMI of an existing EC2 instance with decreased EBS storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running on AWS. I want to clone it without rebooting it. I am using the AWS Management Console to do it. Hence, I have done the following:

1. select instance right-click -> image and templates -> create image
2. In the opened dialog I have given: image name, enabled No reboot.
3. Now in Volume Type, I can only see EBS which is 1000 GB. I have the option to reduce the size which I did to 10 GB.

I was wondering what could be the problem with doing that? Even with 10 GB AMI creation process is taking too much time, it's been 1 hr. Did anyone try this before?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what could be the problem with doing that?

The problem is that you can't reduce EBS volume size. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/modify-volume-requirements.html):

> Decreasing the size of an EBS volume is **not supported**. However, you can create a smaller volume and then migrate your data to it using an **application-level tool** such as rsync.

Basically, it means you can't decrease the size, only increase it. To use smaller volume, you have to **migrate your data** yourself to new, smaller volume.

So your AMI can't have smaller volume then the original instance.